# Proving or refuting that $(x+y)^{\alpha}\leq C(x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha}), x,y>0$ and $\alpha>1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For all $x,y>0$ and all $\alpha>1$, is true that  $(x+y)^{\alpha}\leq C(x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha})$ for some constant $C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose, w.l.o.g. $x \geq y > 0$. Then we need to show
$$(1 + z)^{\alpha} \leq C(1 + z^{\alpha}),$$
where $z \in (0, 1]$.

$$(1 + z) ^{\alpha} \leq 2^{\alpha} \leq 2^{\alpha} \cdot 1 \leq 2^{\alpha} \cdot (1 + z^{\alpha})$$

Now, take $C = 2^{\alpha}$.

Comment: You get the better (sharp) constant $2^{\alpha-1}$ by convexity but +1 for being short and simple